# Multiple buttons with same class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple buttons with the same class on my page, now when I try to call a method on the click event of the button, that method executes for all of the buttons because they have the same class.

The buttons on my page are dynamically created so I cant give different class to each button.

I am looking for a way to only execute some particular method on the click of the first element with the given class.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using Jquery's [.first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/) function, you can get the first element and then only bind the click event to it.

```js
$(".sameClass").first().on("click", function() { console.log("clicked"); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="sameClass">Button 1</button>
<button class="sameClass">Button 2</button>
<button class="sameClass">Button 3</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Hm, very elegant way

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```js
$("button").each(function(i, item) {
  if(i === 0) {
    $(item).on("click", function() {
      console.log('works only for the first button');
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class"test-class">btn 1</button>
<button class"test-class">btn 2</button>
<button class"test-class">btn 3</button>
<button class"test-class">btn 4</button>
<button class"test-class">btn 5</button>
```

I'm looping through all buttons and adding event listener only for the first of them.